# Automatically entering autoshapes into table cells

Tags: microsoft-word

I have some documentation where the client wants to use a circle shape with different colors to represent which toolset is used for their software. This is a large table with hundreds of entries.

What is the best way to enter all these circles into each table cell?

Copy and paste? Can I do it in a more structured way? For example could I fill in all the table cells with a single text letter representing one of the circles and then do a 'find and replace' on each letter with an autoshape?

Answer (score 0):

Write a [macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-macro-HP005189420.aspx) and bind it to a keyboard shortcut.